# Macro not compiling

Tags: c, macros

Why doesn't this fragment of code compile?

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, field_name) ( \
(type *) ((char *) (ptr) - offsetof(type, field_name)))
```

Error

> C:\list.h:37: error: expected expression before ')' token (type * )((char *) (ptr) - offsetof(type, field_name))) ^

Comment: [This compiles fine.](http://ideone.com/P9phv8) We probably need to see where you are using the macro.

Comment: Do you have a semicolon after the macro definition?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here, try to post more code.

Comment: Maybe you have a space after the backslash, so it's not escaping the newline.

Comment: To confirm, is the macro definition or its usage at line 37?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for an error to be produced by the compiler on the macro definition is that the definition ends prematurely and the second line is taken as code to compile.  This will happen if there are extra white space characters between the `\` and the end of line.  Either  or tabs or possibly an unexpected carriage return if the file was moved from a Windows environment to a Linux or Mac system.

Make the macro fit on one line:

```
#define container_of(ptr, t, m) ((t*)((char*)(ptr) - offsetof(t, m)))
```